# dhtmlxToolbar button length

Tags: button, toolbar, dhtmlx

I use dhtmlxToolbar inside dhtmlxTabbar. And I have the next toolbar structure:

```
var tl=tabbar.cells("home").attachToolbar();  
tl.setIconsPath("dhx/imgs/");
tl.addButtonSelect("scope", 3, "all",[["reload","obj","load","reset.gif"],["all","obj","all","true.gif"],["deal","obj","myjob","pencil_go.png"],["unfinish","obj","inflow","reload.png"],["finish","obj","finish","logout.gif"]],"true.gif",null,true,false,null,"select");
tl.addSeparator("s1",4);
tl.addInput("keyword",6,"",100);
tl.setItemToolTip("keyword", "input keyword to search");
tl.addButton("refresh",7,"refresh","refresh.gif");
tl.setItemToolTip("refresh", "");
tl.addSeparator("s2",8);
tl.addButton("search",9,"search","search.gif");
tl.setItemToolTip("search", "");
tl.addSeparator("s3",22);
tl.addButton("selectcol",23,"addcolumn","select_all.gif");
tl.setItemToolTip("selectcol", "");
tl.addSeparator("s5",12);
tl.addButton("add",13,"new","new.gif");
tl.setItemToolTip("add", "");
tl.addSeparator("s7",16);
tl.addButton("remove",17,"remove","remove.gif");
tl.setItemToolTip("remove", "");
tl.addSeparator("s9",20);
tl.addButton("import",21,"import","import.gif");
tl.setItemToolTip("import", "");
tl.addSeparator("s10",24);
tl.addButton("export",25,"export","export.gif");
tl.setItemToolTip("export", "");
tl.addSeparator("s11",26);
tl.addButton("upload",27,"upload","upload.gif");
tl.addSeparator("s12",28);
tl.addButton("download",29,"download","download.gif");
tl.setItemToolTip("download", "");
tl.addSeparator("s13",30);
tl.addButton("report",31,"report","grid.gif");
tl.setItemToolTip("report", "");
tl.addSeparator("s580","586");
tl.addButton("btns1016","587","button1","");
tl.addSeparator("s997",9992);
tl.addButton("help",9993,"","help.gif");
tl.setItemToolTip("help", "online help");
tl.addButton("settings", 9994, "","settings.gif");
tl.setItemToolTip("settings", "todevelope");
tl.addSeparator("s999","9998");
tl.addText("rowcount","9999","");
```

Some of buttons (from the end of list) can’t be showed because there are no left-right “scroll” arrows. What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no “scroll” mode in dhtmlxTabbar. But you can try dhtmlxRibbon, where you can collect some items you need in blocks [like here](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxRibbon/samples/03_block/01_init_from_object.html)